# I need to do a function that calculates the item prices without storing them in the database django

Tags: python, django

I need to do a function which calculates the prices of the items without storing them in the database because the prices of the items change daily,
I have scratched the price of the day and I need the items to be calculated based on this price

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    prdct_name = models.CharField(max_length=17, verbose_name=_("Article "))
    prdct_category = models.ForeignKey("Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    prdct_description = models.TextField(verbose_name=_("Description"))
    prdct_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/',verbose_name=_("Image"), blank=True, null=True)
    # prdct_img
    prdct_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, verbose_name=_("Prix "))
    prdct_cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, verbose_name=_("Prix promotionel "))
    prdct_weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, verbose_name=_("Poid "))
    prdct_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, verbose_name=_("Date Creation "))
    prdct_genre = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=_("Genre "))
    prdct_matiere = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=_("Matiere "))
    prdct_titrage = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=_("titrage "))
    prdct_in_stock = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_("in_stock "))
    prdct_slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)
```

the function to scrape the price from the site

```
def get_prixmatiere():
    # get price from cpor
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    response = requests.get("https://www.exampl.com")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text , 'lxml')
    product_price = soup.find_all("td",{"class" : "price"})[0].text.replace('€', '').replace(' ', '')
    # calculate price
    prixdug = float(product_price) / 4 * 3 / 1000 * 210 - 500
    prixmatiere = float(product_price) / 4 * 3 / 1000 * 210
    return prixmatiere
```

i need to get the price of the item

```
def calc_price_item(self):
    self.dailyprice = get_prixmatiere()
    item_price = self.prdct_price + self.dailyprice * self.prdct_weight
    return item_price
```

and then display it

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.
from .models import Product, ProductImage, Category
from django.core.paginator import Paginator




# function get all product
def product_list(request):
    product_list = Product.objects.all()[:5]        # get all product in variable le model doit etre importe depuis la class

    context = {
        'product_list' : product_list,       # contexte dictionaire variable qui contien les produit = product_list pour lutuliser dans les loupe dans le views
        
                }

    return render(request, 'Product/product_list.html', context)  # retourne la requete + le nom du dossier(dans le templates) + context



def product_detail(request, slug, id):
    product_detail = Product.objects.get(prdct_slug=slug)
    images = ProductImage.objects.filter(prdct_product_id=id)
    cat_parent = Category.objects.filter(level='0')


    context = {'product_detail' : product_detail,
                'images' : images,
                'cat_parent': cat_parent,
                }

    return render(request, 'Product/product_detail.html', context)



def category_product(request, id, slug):
    cat_slug = Category.objects.get(cat_slug=slug)
    category_product =  Category.objects.filter(parent_id=id)
    product = Product.objects.filter(prdct_category=id)

    paginator = Paginator(product, 20) # Show 20 contacts per page.

    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    product = paginator.get_page(page_number)


    context = {

            'id' : id,
            'cat_slug' : cat_slug,
            'category_product': category_product,
            'product': product,

            }


    return render(request, 'Product/category_product.html', context)
```

Comment: 1. Make ajax call from page category_product.html to function in backend, which parses price from another site on-fly. But this can be really slow. 2. Run regularly with crontab your parsing function and write parsed price directly into database.

Comment: please i am new to django it is not possible to do it with python instead of ajax

Comment: what do you mean by "dynamical" if it's ok that the price is calculated on your server when the page is loaded, than you can easily do it with python. If you want the price to be recalculated every second or so without reloading the page, than you need code that runs client side (i.e. ajax or javascript), that makes a request and run your python code.

Comment: I want it to be calculated on the server side with python code every time the site is loaded but I can't manage Do you have a code to suggest me please

Answer (score 0):

I got what I wanted by doing this

F() expressions can be used to execute arithmetic operations (+, -, * etc.) among model fields

without forgetting to import modul F

```
from django.db.models import F
```

views.py

```
prixmatiere = get_prixmatiere()
product_list = Product.objects.all()[:5].annotate(prixgram=F('prdct_price') + int(prixmatiere)).annotate(prixopiece=F('prixgram') * F('prdct_weight'))
```

Now the items in `product_list` have an extra column named `prixgram` and `prixopiece` contains the values